# Chaining pipewire sinks for a streaming setup

Tags: configuration, pipewire

Good evening!

I'm trying to create a streaming setup for me and my buddies to hang out via Skype and I'm really struggling with the audio part. There are two problems :

1. The microphone only transmits on the left channel. I would like for my microphone to be transmitted to both audio channels. For this, according to the documentation, ( https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices ) I need to create a `mono-sink` where I pour in the microphone then transmit it to my `friend sink`. This blogpost ( https://blogshit.baka.fi/2021/07/pipewire-microphone/ ) seems to cover this use case but I have no media-session.d file.
2. I would like to pour in some applications and other audio sources such as my guitar in the `friend sink` and I would like to hear what's in it, except for my microphone (maybe only hear my microphone as a one time test).

How do I achieve this? How do I know how to name the configuration file since they seem to have specific names in the documentation? How do I pour my application audio? Do I need a separate sink for myself? How do I find the device names for pipewire?

Here is my `pactl info` output

```
shaddox@pop-os:/usr/share/pipewire$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 660
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: shaddox
Host Name: pop-os
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.usb-Grace_Design_SDAC-00.iec958-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.usb-Yamaha_Corporation_Steinberg_UR22mkII-00.analog-stereo
Cookie: 3fff:d574
```

If it helps, here is my `arecord -l` output

```
shaddox@pop-os:/usr/share/pipewire$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC887-VD Alt Analog [ALC887-VD Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Webcam [C922 Pro Stream Webcam], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 4: UR22mkII [Steinberg UR22mkII], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here is my `aplay -l` output:

```
shaddox@pop-os:/usr/share/pipewire$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SDAC [SDAC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [22M35]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 4: UR22mkII [Steinberg UR22mkII], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I only use the Steinberg UR22mkII for guitar recording and the microphone while the SDAC one is where I listen to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, once you formulate your own question, it sort of gives you an idea of what to look out for. First of all, I needed to create two virtual devices which will serve as a base of operations. This file will be named `~/.config/pipewire/pipewire.conf.d/10-coupled-skype-stream.conf` . How did I come to that conclusion, you may ask? The source of truth finds itself in `/usr/share/pipewire`! Now, onto the file contents:

```
context.modules = [
    {   name = libpipewire-module-loopback
            args = {
                node.description = "Steinberg Front Left"
                capture.props = {
                    node.name = "capture.mono-micorphone"
                    audio.position = [ FL ]
                    target.object = "alsa_input.usb-Yamaha_Corporation_Steinberg_UR22mkII-00.analog-stereo"
                    stream.dont-remix = true
                    node.passive = true
                }
                playback.props = {
                    media.class = "Audio/Source"
                    node.name = "mono-microphone"
                    audio.position = [ MONO ]
                }
            }
    }
    {   name = libpipewire-module-loopback
        args = {
            audio.position = [ FL FR ]
            capture.props = {
                media.class = Audio/Sink
                node.name = skype_sink
                node.description = "Virtual Skype sink"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I found the name of the devices with the help of a simple program called `Simple Wireplumber GUI`. What the first pair will do is that it will create a tether from the left channel of the source to a new, virtual, MONO one.

The second part of the configuration file creates something called a `sink`, which is just a place where you dump the audio stuff you want everyone to hear.

Now, you use a piece of software called `qpwgraph` or `Helvum` to tether what you want everyone to hear to the sink. Left channel goes to the left channel, right channel goes to the right. For the MONO source, it goes to both channels.

Once you had enough of hearing your voice for testing, look around the aforementioned program for a loopback tether and sever it.

Hope this will be of help to others.